# Event binding in Angular2 with vanilla javascript

Tags: angular

I am using Angular2 and would like to stick to using vanilla javascript.

Does anybody know how to achieve event binding with vanilla javascript?

Comment: That is what angular does not want you to do.

Comment: @Jigar I dont care

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out,

There are actually two ways to do it:

```
<div (click)="myAction()"></div>
<div on-click="myAction()"></div>
```

Then in your component:

```
Class({
        constructor: function() {},
        myAction: function() {
            console.log("hi world");
        }
      }
```